# python for loop using lambda syntax

Tags: python, function, lambda

is there a way to do the same thing as this

```
for i in range(len(x) // 4):
    a, b, c, d = x[i*4: i*4+4]
```

using a single line lambda. and YES i want to use lambda.

Comment: I'll just say that I think using lambda here is a poor choice. All it will do is decrease readability. Unless you're playing code golf, I don't see a reason to do this. Just because something is on one line doesn't make it run faster.

Comment: i used exec to put the entire function in to the lambda, however it only returned the first item from the loop instead of all of them. and you could say its for appearances

Comment: this code doesn't do anything except assigns `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` - is that what you want to happen on one line?

Comment: yes it needs to be in a for loop. there is multiple lists that need to be returned

Comment: Your code doesn't return multiple lists.  It repeatedly assigns individual elements of x to a, b, c, and d.

Comment: sorry i meant that i want it returns multiple sets of four from a list. the answers posted so far only return the first one.

Comment: @user2602977 That is because your original example only returns the first one (well actually the last one), but the point is that they have turned your example into a function as you asked.  You need be more specific if you want them to give you the solution you want.

Comment: OK, based on OP's explanation that he wanted to add other code to the loop to operate on a, b, c, and d, I think I know what he's after.  Added a new answer below to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the OP meant his code fragment to be a framework for a loop and not actually complete code for what he was trying to do.  This is probably closer to his intent:

```
val = []
for c in range(len(x)//4):
    val.append(x[c*4:c*4+4])

for a, b, c, d in val:

    ...  do something with a, b, c, d  ...
```

For the example list from his comments above:

```
x = ['1', '1377877381', 'off', '0', 
     '2', '1377886582', 'on', '0', 
     '3', '1376238596', 'off', '0', 
     '4', '1377812526', 'off', '0']
```

`val` ends up containing

```
[['1', '1377877381', 'off', '0'],
 ['2', '1377886582', 'on', '0'],
 ['3', '1376238596', 'off', '0'],
 ['4', '1377812526', 'off', '0']]
```

An equivalent line using `map()` and `lambda` looks like this:

```
val = map(lambda y: x[y*4:y*4+4], range(len(x)//4))
```

One could now loop over this call to map, assigning to a, b, c, d, and do whatever:

```
for a, b, c, d in map(lambda y: x[y*4:y*4+4], range(len(x)//4)):

    ...  more code ...
```

Hope that helps a bit.

Of course, the more efficient way to do this (particularly for long lists) would be to use `itertools.imap()` and `xrange()` (in python 2.x.  If you're using Python 3.x, just leave it "range.")  This approach doesn't actually construct the complete resulting list, but still allows iterating over it.

Here's my Python 2.x version:

```
from itertools import imap

for a, b, c, d in imap(lambda y: x[y*4:y*4+4], xrange(len(x)//4)):

    ...  more code  ...
```

Comment: i was able to use `val = list(map(lambda y: self.function_here(args[y*4:y*4+4]), range(len(args)//4)))` correctly. thank you